# Swift: Cannot index empty buffer

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, fatal-error

I'm getting the error

> Fatal Error: Cannot Index Empty Buffer

when I quickly start scrolling in my collection view as soon as the view is loaded. The error is thrown at the first line in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055177/how-do-i-prevent-cellforitematindexpath-from-executing-before-i-have-my-data-rea) have given me a couple of ideas on how to not update the collection view until data is loaded, but can someone explain to me why that is even necessary? If `posts` is empty, `numberOfItemsInSection` should return 0, and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` would not yet be called.

```
var posts:[Post] = []

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    getMyPosts()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count as Int
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var p = posts[indexPath.row] // Chrashes here
    // Dequeue cell and so on
}

func getMyPosts(){
    self.posts = []
    Alamofire.request(Api.Router.MyPosts).validate().responseObject{
        (request, response, posts: PostCollection?, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.posts = posts!.getPosts()
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need
 override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
as return 1

put return 0

Section is not required in your case.